# Unable to detect if an element exists on a page or not in Puppeteer

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, request, puppeteer

I'm writing a bot for a pokemon MMORPG game. I wrote a script to login to my account and move around, the problem is that when I move around, I sometimes find a pokemon and then a new div is created which has the pokemon's data. I also get a button (with the id '#catch') to catch the pokemon. So I wrote the script such that it would check for the #catch button. Here's my code

```js
while (true) {
    await page.waitFor(500);
    await page.keyboard.press("ArrowDown");
    if ((await page.$("input#catch")) != null) {
      console.log("Pokemon Found!");
    } else {
      console.log("No Pokemon Found");
    }
```

however, I get 'No Pokemon Found' every single time, even if there is one.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if element exist by using vanilla javascript

```
if(document.getElementById('catch').length > 0){
    console.log("Pokemon Found!");
}else{
    console.log("No Pokemon Found");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found putting 'WaitFor's in code not very reliable or efficient.  If you make them too small, if there is a delay from networking or other reasons, then you have failures.  If you make them huge, then your code take for ever to do.  In my code I've been [waitForSelector](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagewaitforselectorselector-options).  It has a wait/timeout that can be enlarged.

Example:

```
async clickSomeButton(cssSelector) {
    if (await page.waitForSelector(cssSelector, 10000)) {
        await page.click(cssSelector);
        return;
    }
    return fail;
}
```